# Widget configurer

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a program written in PyQt that has a lot of content. The basic way I've been doing it is using a stacked widget with all the content on pages and buttons to navigate through the pages.

However, a lot of the pages are just the same stuff with maybe a couple of different things. What I've been doing is:

1. Initializing all the variables for the widgets
2. Creating a dictionary using the index as a string version of the variable name
3. Using the key as a list containing all the widgets settings
4. Using a `for` loop to recursively pass the values to a function that configures the widget

I'm wondering if anyone has any recommendations to shorten or simplify this code. Coding suggestions are welcome as well.

```
def widgetConfigurer(widgetType, xPos, yPos, xSize, ySize, name, image=None, styleSheet=None):
    widgetType.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(xPos, yPos, xSize, ySize))
    widgetType.setObjectName(_fromUtf8(name))

    if image != None:
        widgetType.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(image)))

    if styleSheet != None:
        widgetType.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8(styleSheet))

...
self.someLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.firstPage)
self.someButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.firstPage)
self.someCheckBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.firstPage)
...
Bunch more widgets here
...

firstPageDict = {
    "someLabel": [self.someLabel, -20, 70, 891, 551, None, "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"]
    "someButton": [self.someButton, 140, 90, 91, 41, None, None]
    "someCheckBox": [self.someCheckBox, 260, 390, 71, 21, None, None]
}

for widgetName, widgetSettings in firstPageDict.items():
            widgetConfigurer(widgetSettings[0], widgetSettings[1], widgetSettings[2], widgetSettings[3], widgetSettings[4], widgetName, widgetSettings[6], widgetSettings[7])
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quite that you've chosen to use a dictionary here as it is a readable way to group your widgets with their initialisation arguments, but I see two problems:

1. You are labelling each widget twice: once in `self` and once in the dictionary.
2. Your arguments are begging to be unpacked with `*`

I would tackle both of these by grouping the name, the initialisation and the arguments into one structure, and modifying the definition of widgetConfigurer so that you can unpack the arguments into it:

```
self.widgets = {
    # name : (widget, xpos, ypos, ... )
    'someLabel': (QtGui.QLabel(self.firstPage), -20, 70, ... ),
    ... }

def widgetConfigurer(name, widget, xPos, yPos, ... ):
    ...

for name, args in self.widgets.iteritems():
    widgetConfigurer(name, *args)
```

The issue with this is that it's a bit ugly referencing a particular widget `someLabel = self.widgets['someLabel'][0]`.   The most important thing is that you're unpacking those lists of arguments, everything else is just renaming for readability.

One other thing: You should use `is` when comparing objects to `None` rather than `==` or `!=`.

```
if image is not None:
   ...
```

Comment: Genius! I was looking for a way to initialize the variables inline, but couldn't figure out how to access them.